# How to add a Bounce animation effect for logo in Android splash screen?

Tags: android, animation, splash-screen

Well i have create a splash screen with the logo at the center,now I want to add animation to it like the logo is droped from top of the screen and it bounced once and stop in center of the screen.

can any one help me out .

Comment: Check this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/ , http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/behold-the-animation-magic-of-an-android-interpolator/

Comment: Look at this great animation examples: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Answer (score 2):

```
First position your logo to the center take reference of that logo and check below code : 

bounce.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

    <scale
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>

use abow xml in your splash activity like this : 

Animation an2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.bounce);
your_logo.startAnimation(an2);
```